# Where can I find official Google Maps JavaScript API new feature news and release info?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

There appear to be significant updates to the Google Maps JavaScript API today.  In particular, addition of Street View pinch to zoom and motion controlled panning.  Where could I find more info about these changes and any upcoming changes?

I found no mentions on maps.googleblog.com, googlemapsmania.blogspot.com, and developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript.

[UPDATE] Our code automatically picked up the 3.26.0 experimental version of the API [around August 15th](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/TmdlvfoXYYY), which must include the pinch to zoom and motion controlled panning features.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have used Google better, but however:

Release Notes: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases

Feed: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/feeds/releases.xml

Google notify group: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify

Comment: None of the links mentioned describe the new features that appear to be added.

Comment: Google doesn't provide many information about their plans of new features. There you see the release notes of the newest versions and you can keep uptodate by subscribing the feeds, but there is no official milestone list for the APIs with all the plans as far as I know. Perhaps you can find some hints in the [Google Maps JS API v3 Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/google-maps-js-api-v3), but that's some work ;)